# How to develop web application for managing VMWare ESXi using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sdk, wsdl, esxi

I want to develop a web application using nodejs which will manage my VMWare ESXi hosts.

Where should I start? I have seen Java, C# and Perl APIs are available, but how to go with javascript(nodejs)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the VMware Web Services SDK and interact with your vSphere environment using SOAP. There is a WSDL available in the SDK, and you can use something like [node-soap](https://github.com/milewise/node-soap) to work with it.